# How to print two list results together

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have two lists as

```
foreach (var a in _teams)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}

foreach (var b in _wins)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

Each list have same number of values. Right now i am printing each values separtely but how can i print each value of a or b together .

_teams list return Australia, England , USA
_wins list return 5,6,7

I want to print like that Australia 5, England 6, USA 7

Updated *
i am creating xml nodes so basically i dont want to print it together. I want values like
Australia than 5 than England than 6 so on and i will create xml nodes like

```
<Team>Australia</Team>
<Win>5</Win>
<Team>England </Team>
<Win>6</Win>
```

...so on

Comment: Use an indexed `for` loop? Or better yet, combine that information into a single class and store *those* in the list.

Comment: What are the types of the lists? List<something> or Something[]?

Comment: Look into [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: i have updated my question sorry may be i did not explain my question well can you see my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var a in _teams.Zip(_wins, (t, w) => new { t, w }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.t + " " + a.w);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for(i = 0; i < _teams.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(_teams[i] + " ");
    Console.Write(_wins[i]);
    if(i < _teams.Length - 1)
        Console.Write(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the zip function on IEnumerable. Something like this:

```
var lst1 = new List<string>(){"One", "Two","Three"};
var lst2 = new List<string>(){"A", "B","C"};
var combined = lst1.Zip(lst2, (fst,snd) => {return fst + ":" + snd;});
foreach (var item in combined)
{
    Console.WriteLine (item);
}
```

Zip will take two seperate lists and allow you to build a single view into both.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below menioned code

```
        List<string> _terms = new List<string>();
        List<string> _wins = new List<string>();
        _terms.Add("Australia");
        _wins.Add("5");
        using (var e1 = _terms.GetEnumerator())
        using (var e2 = _wins.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
            {
                var item1 = e1.Current;
                var item2 = e2.Current;

                // use item1 and item2
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop...

```
for (int i = 0; i < teams.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(_teams[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(_wins[i]);
}
```

... but Dictionary is a better solution:

```
Dictionary<string, int> _teams = new Dictionary<string, int>();
_teams.Add("Australia", 5);
_teams.Add("England", 6);
...
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in _teams )
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

[MSDN Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_teams.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x +" " + _wins[_teams.IndexOf(x)]));
```

We use the `IndexOf` method to get index of the current string from `_teams`, and get the element at that index of `_wins`.

However, if this is a 1-to-1 map between team and it's wins, a `Dictionary` would be my preferred data structure.